# Do gravitational waves lose energy through interaction with i.e. matter or magnetic fields?

Tags: gravitational-waves

Gravitational waves dilute while traversing space like any other radiation, and their amplitudes are proportional to r<sup>-2</sup>, that's a basic. But do they lose energy while traversing through matter or something else (i.e. space with magnetic fields, or whatever), too, by interaction with it ?

(The question "Where does gravitational waves' energy go?" doesn't focus on traversing matter of fields)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very original, and I have never seen it addressed, so here are my own hastily prepared thoughts on the matter.  Caveat lector.

You can gain some insight into the fate of gravitational waves by pursuing the analogy with electromagnetic waves, which get both scattered and absorbed.  EM waves get scattered by matter that responds to the electric field -- free charges, good conductors, or polarizable objects.  They can also get absorbed when dissipative processes are at work -- in imperfect conductors, or dielectrics with lagging response.

Dissipative processes generally involve reequilibration, which can be either fast or slow.  In imperfect conductors, electrons accelerated by the field ultimately lose their momentum by collisions with positive ions.  In water, it takes roughly 20 ps for the polar molecules to reorient.

When GR waves passes through a galaxy, the tidal forces will deform orbits and objects, and the waves will surely undergo some scattering.  But what of dissipation?  Near misses by stars and lesser objects redistribute momentum slowly, but the tidal disturbance may either be brief (if the wave comes from a catastrophic collision) or periodic (if radiated by a binary star system).  MHD dissipation within individual stars acts faster.

As for magnetic fields in empty space, they would push back when squeezed by tidal forces, much as in MHD, so scattering is to be expected, but not absorption, for lack of dissipative processes.

Comment: There may be a cottage industry around, such as: Anile, A. M., and V. Pirronello. "High-frequency gravitational waves in a dissipative fluid." *Il Nuovo Cimento B* (1971-1996) **48.1** (1978): 90-101.

Comment: Could you then use this scattering and, say, LIGO to observe objects that the waves have passed through?

Comment: As far as I understand your answer, there are two things to happen besides simple dilution in space: scattering, which would produce more (weaker) gravitational waves, and dissipation when matter gets deformed by tidal effects. I presume that the dissipation ends up in warming up the matter ?

Comment: Just another follow up question ... given a fictional GW detector (or an array of 'em), with precision and sensitivity by far better than LIGO etc., I presume it would be possible to analyze the GWs (or their scatter) for effect traces resulting from the things present in the space traversed ?

Comment: Ooops - last comment duped the follow up question of Beta Decay. Sorry for that. But I presume that such an attempt would require detector(s) which are very far better than LIGO (or projected LISA). With those: Yes, I think. @Cosmas: Tried a look into that paper. That's heavy stuff for people not dedicated to be brilliant cosmologists ...

Comment: Dissipation almost always involves heating.  I can imagine other irreversible changes that would soak up energy, but I can't see how GW would trigger them.  I doubt that Ultra-Ligo could tell distinguish an attenuated wave from an un-attenuated wave.  You would need to compare two detections of a wave front from the same source -- one detector in this galaxy, an the other in some other galaxy.  Good luck with telepathic communication.

Comment: At the galactic level, dissipation might involve pumpiong up the kinetic energy of orbits (of binary star systems or planets).  A periodic GW in resonance with the orbital period would have the greatest effect.